# Why amqsput command is dividing my data and push to the message queue?

Tags: message-queue, ibm-mq

While testing my application, I tried with a string taking space of some 200KB. But `amqsput`  divided my request in multiple chunks. I am not sure why it's happening. If I reduce the size to some 100KB then it works fine.

I am using following command to push data into the message queue:

`amqsput MESSAGE_QUEUE MQM < /home/usr/sampleRequest.xml`

This `sampleRequest.xml` contains an XML formatted as one line. I don't know much about MQ admins/configuration and want an idea what's wrong.

Why it's dividing my data and push it to queue when file size is greater than a certain value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

amqsput & amqsget are simple applications for putting and getting small messages to and from a queue.  If you look at the code for amqsput (i.e. amqsput0.c), you will see that the buffer size used is 65535 (64KB).

There are lots of programs that are better suited for your type of testing.  There is a long list of C sample MQ applications [here](http://www.capitalware.com/mq_code_c.html).  The 2 that you might want to use are file2msg and msg2file.  There is also Paul Clarke's [QLoad](http://www.mqgem.com/qload.html) program (it used to be SupportPac).